# iterate over firestore batch elements

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

What is the recommended way to iterate over write batch operations?

```
commit(batch:WriteBatch){
    if(batch does not contain a write to /Documents/users){
      batch.update(/Documents/Users/uid,{lastSeen: timestamp})
    }
    batch.commit()
}
```

Edit: the project I am working on has a database service that manages all the interactions with firestore so all the writes are tunneled trough a method on this database service.
The final goal is to update the user profile with a lastSeen timestamp every time the user makes a document write.
However a profile update is a document write and adding batch.update() for the same document on the same batch could lead to data loss because it generates two consecutive writes within a period of time shorter than one second.

Comment: Short answer below, but it sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - so you might want to update your question with what you're trying to actually accomplish by iterating over the batch.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.writebatch) there is no way to iterate over the contents of a `WriteBatch` object. If you need to know what you put in the batch, you'll have to track that yourself.